# Laravel 7 - what needs to be done to put site in production mode?

Tags: laravel, development-environment, production

What are the steps that need to be done when putting a site from development to production?

I am aware of:

- in my .env file set APP_ENV=production
- in my .env file set APP_DEBUG=false
- I know that the app.js file should be `minified` even tough i dont know yet what that means..

is there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: `php artisan optimize`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a section about deploying a Laravel application to production in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/deployment).

To sum it up:

1. `composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev`, note that if you still want the require-dev packages you can leave off the `--no-dev` option
2. `php artisan config:cache`
3. `php artisan route:cache`
4. `php artisan view:cache`

You can read more about compiling assets [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#running-mix) and about minification [here](https://www.imperva.com/learn/performance/minification/).

> Minification is the process of minimizing code and markup in your web
> pages and script files. It’s one of the main methods used to reduce
> load times and bandwidth usage on websites. Minification dramatically
> improves site speed and accessibility, directly translating into a
> better user experience. It’s also beneficial to users accessing your
> website through a limited data plan and who would like to save on
> their bandwidth usage while surfing the web.

You can minify your assets with Laravel Mix the following way:

**Mix version 5**

```
// Run all Mix tasks and minify output...
npm run prod
```

**Mix version 6**

```
// Run all Mix tasks and minify output...
npx mix --production
```

You can read more about the `APP_ENV` environment variable [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#determining-the-current-environment):

> The current application environment is determined via the APP_ENV
> variable from your .env file.

As far as I am aware this does not change much out of the box, but if you use additional third party packages or Laravel packages like for example [Telescope](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/telescope), it determines how these packages function, for example if the `APP_ENV` value is set to `local`, Telescope will record all data and every user will have access to the Telescope routes.

You can see a example [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/telescope#dashboard-authorization) and [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/telescope#filtering-entries).

Comment: thank you very much.. just a little question: is this additional to the change of the .env file or is it done automatically with one of these steps?

Comment: You will need to change your `.env` as well.

Comment: thank you! what does the APP_ENV actually do? debug is clear, but app_ENV id ont understand.. also tried to read it up but still dont understand

Comment: @sharkyenergy I added an explanation about `APP_ENV` to the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: thank you very much! I've followed your steps and now the site is giving 500 errror: Class 'Facade\Ignition\IgnitionServiceProvider' not found

Comment: Do you see this error in your browser or in the logs? Did you set your `APP_DEBUG` to false?

Comment: The problem is that ignition is not installed after running `composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev` since it is listed in the require-dev packages, the reason being that you shouldn't turn on the debug mode in a production environment. If you still want the require-dev packages you can run `composer install --optimize-autoloader` instead. Additionally you should test if the deployment works in your local environment on your computer first instead on the server directly.

Comment: thank youv ery much Remul, its working now! :) please add it to the answer as alternative to the first step..

Answer (score 1):

There are many things to do to make your site production ready.

- Caching (Queries, Views ETC)
- Use of webpack (To bundle assets & minify them)
- Use cdn for the asset bundles (So they load faster which will increase your website loading speed)
- Deploying website on cloud for better resources.
- ETC

So you can't just simply make a website production ready by updating your .env file.

You might need to read some articles on google about `laravel production ready website`